# Auto-load spring components using java configuration

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a few spring components and it would be a part of a library - jar.

I want the components to get loaded automatically by the applications that have the jar in the classpath.

```
@Component
public class AComponent {
}
```

I tried creating a configuration class and doing a component scan, but, the configuration is not loading.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(BasePackages="")
public class ComponentConfig {
}
```

Can you please suggest a solution? It's a non-spring-boot application.

Comment: How do you load your application context to get all the spring beans?

Comment: You should look at Spring Boot and the documentation on how to write autoconfiguration classes.

Comment: Are the applications using your library Spring apps (i.e. are they loading an ApplicationContext)?

Comment: @chrylis yes, i understand that approach and that's why mentioned that it's a non-spring-boot application explicitly.

Comment: @JamieBisotti Yes, they are spring applications and i dont want them to make any changes other than including the library in the classpath.

Comment: basically you want to change the non-spring-boot behaviour of your clients in order to auto-load an anotated component of your library? maybe I'm worng but if the client doesn't scan explicitly your desired beans seems to me they can't be loaded magically...

Comment: What you are trying to do is considered rude behavior. If I'm not using Spring Boot, I don't want you to jump in and alter my application context automatically. Provide a default configuration class (and you might as well register it for autoconfiguration) and let the client `@Import` it if desired.

Answer (score 0):

As you are writing a library, that uses Spring, I do not believe it is possible for the client applications to make zero changes. Your library has a collection of Spring beans that must be loaded into an ApplicationContext. At the very least, the clients will need to include your @Configuration/@Component classes (via scanning).

Good luck.